# Что нужно изучить по сетям базово

Tags: linux, сеть, системное-программирование

Ребята, хочу устроится работать в местную больницу системным администратором, но нет точного плана, что изучать и максимум, что знаю, это подключение проводов к коммутатору и т п.  Хочу уметь работать с интернет проводами, настраивать IP и т.п с компьютера. Уметь прописывать некоторые команды, чтоб сеть была защищенной и уметь увеличивать пропускную способность и т.п.

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли изучить базовые вещи за период 1-3 месяца не углубляясь для начала, и что нужно изучать

Comment: В большинстве мед учреждений будут рады даже если ты просто не бухаешь в подсобке)

Answer (score 4):

Для такой работы нужно научиться искать решения. Не пытайся все запомнить. Защищенную сеть без опыта никто не даст строить.

Для настройки сети изучи:

- icmp,
- dhcp,
- tcp(syn,fin,ack),
- udp,
- dns,
- arp,
- ipv4 (маски, подсети, unicast,broadcast,multicast,anycast)
- маршрутизация и маршруты
- ethernet (формат кадра, как работает)
- 802.1q,
- iptables(базовые настройки, как сохранять и загружать),
- nat
- "linux packet flow",
- 802.11 (формат кадра, как работает, форвард),

Не углубляясь достаточно понять принцип, во многих местах статьи из википедии хаптит.